# Creating your own keywords in java?

Tags: java

I was wondering if this would work. In java, you use 'null' to make something nothing. Would this work?

```
Object nil = null;
```

Could I then use `nil` instead of `null`? Thanks!

Comment: You've just declared a variable called `nil` and assigned the value `null` to it. `nil` is just a name. It's not a keyword. You can use it wherever it's in scope.

Comment: You can use `nil` variable only in the scope where it's defined.

Comment: If the reason you're doing this is to have a Ruby like language on the JVM, you could try JRuby instead. http://jruby.org/

Comment: Best practice is to avoid `null` as much as possible anyway. Hoare called the invention of null a "billion-dollar mistake".

Comment: @OP Why? What would be the point? You already have `null`. Use it.

Comment: @EJP i would surmise its because nil is more familiar syntax in other language of choice, though i would think the one letter more wouldn't make too much of a difference

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't allow for this.

However, if you want to achieve this sort of syntax whilst being able to run your code on a JVM (and with other Java code), you could look at Groovy, which has operator overloading (and with which you could also use DSLs for short syntax which would have similar effects to using custom operators).

Note that defining custom operators (not just overloading) is a big deal in any language, since you would have to be able to alter the lexer and grammar somehow.